# How can I tell which constructor to use on an inner (member) class?

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes

Reflective instantiation of an inner class requires a constructor that takes a synthetic parameter, the instance of the enclosing class. If the inner class is static, then there is no such constructor.

I can tell that a class is an inner class using the [Class.isMemberClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isMemberClass%28%29) method, but I can't see a neat way of determining whether or not the member class is static or not, which is how I would expect to figure out which constructor to call.

Is there a neat way to tell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the [Examining Class Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classModifiers.html) tutorial. I think it's something like

```
Modifier.isStatic(myClass.getModifiers());
```

Answer (score 0):

[David is correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230855/438154) I'm just going to post what you mean by

> Reflective instantiation of an inner class requires a constructor that
>   takes a synthetic parameter, the instance of the enclosing class.

for people like myself that needed to try it out:

```
public class Outer {
    public String value = "outer";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int modifiers = StaticNested.class.getModifiers();
        System.out.println("StaticNested is static: " + Modifier.isStatic(modifiers));

        modifiers = Inner.class.getModifiers();
        System.out.println("Inner is static: " + Modifier.isStatic(modifiers));

        Constructor constructor = Inner.class.getConstructors()[0]; // get the only one
        Inner inner = (Inner) constructor.newInstance(new Outer()); // the constructor doesn't actually take arguments
    }

    public static class StaticNested {

    }

    public class Inner {
        public Inner() {
            System.out.println(Outer.this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
StaticNested is static: true
Inner is static: false
outer
```